# objective-c Object memory management

Tags: objective-c, memory, memory-management

I have this simple class which I know is ok in terms of memory leaks.

```
   @interface location : NSObject {
        NSString *name;
        float lat;
        float lon;
        NSString *subtitle;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *subtitle;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) float lat;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) float lon;


    @end

    @implementation location

    @synthesize name;
    @synthesize lon;
    @synthesize lat;
    @synthesize subtitle;

    -(void)dealloc{
        [name release];
        [subtitle release];
        [super dealloc];
    }

    @end
```

There is retain in the @property  so i release in the dealloc method. Now, my question is: If I alloc one of the strings in a init method or some other method I create, should I do another release? If so, when?

```
@implementation location

@synthesize name;
@synthesize lon;
@synthesize lat;
@synthesize subtitle;

-(void) init{
      name = [[NSString alloc] init];
 }

-(void)dealloc{
    [name release]; // IS THIS CORRECT?!
    [subtitle release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are assigning value using `self.` notation then you should `release` (as `retain` was called automatically, if you use `synthesize`) if your were using `alloc + init` approach for creating new object. Example:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] init];
self.name = str;
[str release];
```

If you are assigning value using `self.` notation and assigning autoreleased object then you shouldn't `retain` and `release`. Example:

```
NSString *str = [NSString string];
self.name = str;
```

If you are assigning value without `self.` prefix then you should not assign `autorelease` object and should not `release`, you just should `alloc + init` object. Example:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] init];
name = str;
```

Or if you want to `assign` autoreleased object without `self.` prefix then you should retain it. Example:

```
NSString *str = [NSString string];
name = [str retain];
```

In `dealloc` method you should `release objects` if you didn't do that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't need retain here as you are not reatining anything. Your code is same as if all the properties are assigned.

until you don't call self.name, the retain semantics is not applied.

There is a code style which remove that confusion. keep the property name and instance name different and assign instance name to property name at @synthesize.

Like this:

```
@interface location : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
 }

 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *nameProp;


 @end

@implementation location

@synthesize nameProp = name;
```

Comment: By doing this where do you have to release? And how can you set the string by a call?

Comment: if you are inside the location class, just do self.nameProp = nil; to release it, and self.nameProp = newObjet; to replace it with newObject, this will automatically release the previous object assigned to self.nameProp. If you are having a location object named locationObject, just chnage self to locationObject.