# ios initialize an instance inside a function to use outside

Tags: objective-c, ios, instance, retain, analyzer

the xcode analyzer tell me that a method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count:
[image]

but the self.athletes is an object that I need also outside my function... how can I solve this 'warning?
thanks again

the athletes is declared like this:

```
NSMutableArray *athletes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSMutableArray *athletes;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace that line with this one:

```
self.athletes = [NSMutableArray array];
```

I wrote full explanation here : [Memory Management for properties with retain attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392146/objective-c-object-memory-management/7392233#7392233)

Answer (score 1):

Since your property is defined with "retain", using the dot notation will result in an extra retain. The return from the [[NSMutableArray  alloc] init] has a retain count of 1, and then when you set the property using the setter function generated by the property declaration it will have a retain count of 2.

To fix, either:

```
self.athletes = [NSMutableArray array]; // Returns an autoreleased object
```

Or, you could also do this:

```
athletes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // Doesn't use the setter generated by the property declaration, so doesn't retain again.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice way to handle this (and you have already used this pattern while creating UI ).

NSMutableArray *athletesTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

self.athletes = athletesTemp;

[athletesTemp release];

Here you don't need to carry the load of an auto release object.